# Can I permanently remap one colour to another in my bash_profile?

Tags: bash, accessibility

I've got a red-deficient variant of colourblindness. Red text is very difficult for me to read because it's much darker to me than for people with regular colour vision, so when it's on a black background I often can't see what it says unless I copy and paste the content to another window with a different colour scheme.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to remap the colour that the console displays as red presently to a different shade. Presently, red is shown as #c50f1f, I'd like it to be something like #fd574b instead.

Is there a way to do that in my bash_profile or similar which will impact any and all programs or scripts which output either red text or a red background?

I'm using bash in WSL, not sure if that impacts anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something that could be done easily by shifting your terminal emulator's colour palette, rather than configuring bash, could you give it a try?

Comment: The default WSL terminal doesn't have any colour options but I will start using the Windows Terminal application which appears to have that capability. Good suggestion, thanks!